# What is the use of pair class stl in c++ , is it like a data type or a container?

Tags: c++, stl

I basically want to know on which area we can use pair stl, how can we iterate over pair stl. Here is a short code where I have tried to iterate over a pair but it's giving error.

```
int main()
{

    pair<int,int>a;
    a=make_pair(1,22);
    a=make_pair(2,33);
    a=make_pair(3,44);

    for(pair<int,int>::iterator i:a)
    {
        cout<<a.first<<"-->";
        cout<<a.second;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to iterator over something that always has *exactly* two items? And how would the iterator work when those items can be of different types? Can you expand on what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have data with a key/value relationship, a pair may come in handy if the key is also needed.

A pair can only store two elements so your attempt at storing three pairs won't work. Each new pair would replace the old pair. If a number of pairs is what you need, add a container for the type of pair you want. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> a;
    a.emplace_back(1, 22);
    a.emplace_back(2, 33);
    a.emplace_back(3, 44);

    for(auto [First, Second] : a) {
        std::cout << First 
                  << "-->"
                  << Second
                  << "\n";
    }
}
```

> how can we iterate over pair

You can't. If you need to pass the values in the pair to a function taking something iterable as an argument you need to do it manually, like:

```
for(auto p : a) { // a is a std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>
    for(auto value : {p.first, p.second}) {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::pair` is used in the implementation of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

For [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map),

`value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`

Beyond that, `std::pair` is convenient for creating a type that consists of two members.

Answer (score 1):

> is [pair class] like a data type or a container?

All classes are data types. More specifically though, `std::pair` is a class template; It's not a class as such, but its instances are classes.

`std::pair` is not a [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

> what is the use of pair class stl in c++

Its intention is to group two objects together. Instance of the `std::pair` is a class with two member objects. Such class can be defined without the template as well:

```
struct CustomClassWithoutStd {
    int         first;
    std::string second;
};
```

The advantage of `std::pair` over a custom class is that you don't need to specify names for those members, and different pairs with different use cases can be processed identically, because they are the same pair type with same names for each member.

The main disadvantage is that you cannot give names for those members, which often reduces readability of the program.

> I basically want to know on which area we can use pair stl

The standard library uses `std::pair` in the interface of associative containers where the pair groups together the key and the value. So, when you use such containers, you need to use pairs as well.

In my opinion, this was a bad design choice, and a class with properly named members would have been a better one.

> how can we iterate over pair stl

If you have a function template that can accept either part of the pair, you can invoke it with both parts like this (I'm using stream insertion as an example of such template):

```
auto a = std::make_pair(1, 22);
cout << a.first;
cout << a.second;
```